# Can not instantiate proxy of class x - Could not find parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mvp

So I'm trying to implement unit testing into my application and I am trying to mock a number of my constructor arguments to pass through. I've read on here that you are not supposed to Mock a class and instead Mock an interface but I've also read that there isn't much point in implementing an [interface](http://blog.karumi.com/interfaces-for-presenters-in-mvp-are-a-waste-of-time/) for a presenter when implementing the MVP approach.

I've been told that you can pass in the parameters into a constructor by using this line, this is also the line where the error is thrown:

```
               var p = new ImpositionCalculatorPresenter(mockView.Object, mockImpositionCalculatorManager.Object, mockSystemVariablesManager.Object,
    mockSystemVariablesPresenter.Object, mockPrintingDesignManager.Object);
```

Can anyone help me implement a way of passing in the arguments into my constructor when Mocking my presenter?

```
   [TestMethod]
        public void CalculateFinalImpositionPlates() {
            //Need to pass in the managers for dependency injection.
            //Then I need to find a way which will trigger the event to call the method on the presenter
            //Then do my tests
            var mockView = new Mock<IImpositionFormView>();

            mockView.SetupProperty(r => r.FinalImpositionOut, 0);

            //These may have to be manually mocked by me so they don't affect JSON file
            var mockImpositionCalculatorManager = new Mock<IImpositionCalculatorManager>();
            var mockSystemVariablesManager = new Mock<ISystemVariablesManager>();
            var mockSystemVariablesPresenter = new Mock<SystemVariablesPresenter>();
            var mockPrintingDesignManager = new Mock<IPrintingDesignManager>();


            //Fix error allowing me to pass in objects to the contstructor
                   var p = new ImpositionCalculatorPresenter(mockView.Object, mockImpositionCalculatorManager.Object, mockSystemVariablesManager.Object,
        mockSystemVariablesPresenter.Object, mockPrintingDesignManager.Object);

    mockView.SetupProperty(r => r.Presenter == p);

            mockView.Raise(r => r.CalculateFinalImpositionPlates += null);

            Assert.Equals(mockView.Object.Plates, 0);

        }
```

Part of my presenter:

```
public class ImpositionCalculatorPresenter {
    private readonly IImpositionCalculatorManager _impostionFormManager;
    private readonly ISystemVariablesManager _systemVariablesManager;
    private readonly SystemVariablesPresenter _systemVariablesFormPresenter;
    private readonly IPrintingDesignManager _printingDesignManager;
    private readonly string _pathToAppSettings = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}/PrintAppSettings.txt";
    private PagePrintingDesignParameters _printingAppParameters;
    private readonly IImpositionFormView _view;

    public ImpositionCalculatorPresenter(IImpositionFormView View, IImpositionCalculatorManager impositionFormManager,
        ISystemVariablesManager systemVariablesManager, SystemVariablesPresenter systemVariablesFormPresenter, IPrintingDesignManager printingDesignManager) {
        _view = View;
        _impostionFormManager = impositionFormManager;
        _systemVariablesManager = systemVariablesManager;
        _systemVariablesFormPresenter = systemVariablesFormPresenter;
        _printingDesignManager = printingDesignManager;
        InitialiseEvents();
    }
    private void InitialiseEvents() {

        _view.CalculateFinalImpositionPlates += CalculateFinalImpositionPlates;


    }

    private void CalculateFinalImpositionPlates(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //if sheet fed checked, and sheetwise not selected in drop down and sheetsize irregular not select in drop down
        try {
            if (_view.FinalImpositionOut != 0) {
                if (_view.OverridePlates != 0) {
                    _view.Plates = _view.OverridePlates;
                }
                else if (_view.PrintingStyleChecked == PrintingStyle.SheetFed && (_view.CboImposition != "Sheetwise" || _view.CboImposition != "Irregular S\\Wise")) {
                    _view.Plates = _view.ColourSideOne;
                }
                else if (_view.ColourSideOne != 0 && _view.ColourSideTwo != 0) {
                    _view.Plates = _view.ColourSideOne + _view.ColourSideTwo;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            LogErrorToView(this, new ErrorEventArgs(ex.Message));
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You also do not unit test the mock. You mock the dependencies of the subject under test.

Comment: Okay, so I'm trying to unit test my presenter. Does that mean I create a new instance of the presenter instead of mocking it?

Comment: This question is also incomplete. It is missing a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: If that is your subject under test yes. What exactly on the presenter you are trying to test?

Comment: Okay, I will update the code now

Comment: I have updated my code, but it still throws the same error

Comment: This code looks rather chaotic. Way too much going on. No wonder there is so much difficulty to test. Not seeing how much help I can provide given how broad this is due to lack of context.

Comment: It's not really though. I have given you an extract of my presenter which adds subscribers to my events and also the method which I would like to test(CalculateFinalImpositionPlates). I have also shown the unit test which I'm trying to get to test the method mentioned above

Comment: At what line do you get the error? And if *..it doesn't throws the error listed in the titles* is true then what exception does it throw?  What does the signature of `SystemVariablesPresenter` look like?

Comment: I've stated above at what line the error gets thrown at. And it throws the exact error listed in the title. Why do you need to see what the 'SystemVariables' presenter looks like?

Comment: Because SystemVariables seems to be the only non-interface that gets instantiated by the Mock when you create `ImpositionCalculatorPresenter`

Comment: @Andrew I would have to agree with rene's assessment. Based on the updated OP, `SystemVariablesPresenter` and the call to `AppDomain` are the only remaining strongly coupled dependencies may cause issues with mocking in that unit test. And based on your previous question it looks like `presenter = new SystemVariablesPresenter(this, manager);` has dependencies of it's own which would be the cause of the error message when you try to mock the class.

Comment: Hi guys, I took another look at the unit test and you guys are correct. The issue was that the `SystemVariablesPresenter` had a constructor which also needed populating with arguments